# Content-Type и charset= - регламентированы ли пробелы между символами?

Tags: http, https

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот есть http заголовок: Content-Type у этого золовка сооветвенно может быть к примеру значение: charset=utf-8

Подскажите, между charset= и указанием кодировки может быть пробел или два пробела ? Не нашел регламентировано ли это или нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не может.

https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#media.type

> Note: Unlike some similar constructs in other header fields, media type parameters do not allow whitespace (even "bad" whitespace) around the "=" character.